# Gitbook - User icon keeps expanding and hides the 'Edit/Merge' button

Tags: github, gitbook

I have gitbook synchronizing with my github account for my personal wiki.  Lately, the user icon keeps expanding where it now hides my 'Edit/Merge' button.

[Gitbook top section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdzER.png)

When I mouse over these icons, it's says " (You)".

Does anyone know how I can clear this?

Thank you.

I'm not sure what these icons represent.